# The multivariable chain rule in in operator form

Tags: multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

For a function $f = f(x,y)$, we have

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$$

Sometimes we might be interested in the operator $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$; is it valid to write:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$$Thank you!

Comment: I think it's clearer to write $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$, since it acts on functions.

Comment: Yes! This form is used later in differential geometry. In fact (this may be a little advanced): since you are writing $\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}$ you are starting with a path in $R^2$, say $\gamma:t\mapsto (x(t),y(t))$. You can see this as an instance of the push-forward of the tangent vector $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ from $R$ to $R^2$ by $\gamma$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_%28differential%29

Comment: Thanks for the replies @A.Goodier, @Keshav! I'll have a read through the link you reference!